# Upload file using POST in python. Where to look?

Tags: python, post, urllib2

I want to upload and get the result from this website. http://cello.life.nctu.edu.tw/

I tried

```
from poster.encode import multipart_encode
from poster.streaminghttp import register_openers
import urllib2

register_openers()

params = ({"file": open("xaa", "r"),
       "seqtype": "prot",
       "species": "eu"})
datagen, headers = multipart_encode(params)

request = urllib2.Request("http://cello.life.nctu.edu.tw/cgi/main.cgi", datagen, headers)
print urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

but I got an error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 9, in <module>
    a = opener.open("http://cello.life.nctu.edu.tw/cgi/main.cgi", params)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

I have no idea what is wrong here. Could someone point me out. ?  Thanks.

btw. The xaa file looks like this http://pastebin.com/7VK3vvwC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

This is a server error. In other words there is nothing wrong with your code - it's just this page errors out.

Comment: Well, I don't know why. I tried use webpage via web browser and it came up fine. I then accessed the web via webbrowser and found that "http://cello.life.nctu.edu.tw/cgi/main.cgi" also give me 500 error. I tried using main url in script as well but it just link to the main page. It seems like I use the wrong url in script. Could you help me out ?

Comment: @Tg I get that error when I go there directly from my browser, but not when using the form on the main page. My guess is that the script is poorly written and can't handle invalid input, or no input at all. Are you sure your parameters are correct?

Comment: I am not sure about that. How to check those ? For about parameter, I guess it from source but maybe I'm wrong...